# External developer in-app purchases

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I'm an extrnal developer creating an app for one company. So far I've been always doing the development using my own account (testing on my iPhone etc.) and then mailing them the whole XCode project, which they would then submit to the App Store after compiling it on their machine.

Now I need to add in-app purchases and I'm not quite sure how to go about it, seeing how you first need to add the (purchasable) items to iTunesConnect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They need to add you to their developer account and you need to stop using your own account for development. The easiest way to do that is to create a new user account on your machine and set that up for your customer's iTunes account, once they add you. They will also need grant you access to iTunes Connect.

Once they add you to their developer account you will get a popup menu when you login to developer.apple.com asking which account you would like to use for that login session.